# K Means giving poor results

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering, k-means, scikit-learn

I have several user names and their salaries. 
Now I need to cluster user based on their salaries.
I am using KMeans clustering and following is my code

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import pandas as pd

le = LabelEncoder()
data = pd.read_csv('kmeans.data',header=None, names =['user', 'salary'])

# Numerical conversion
data['user'] = le.fit_transform(data['user'])
km = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state= 10, n_init=10, max_iter=500)
km.fit(data)

data['labels'] = le.inverse_transform(data['user'])
data['cluster'] = km.labels_

print data
```

But my results are bad and there are lot of overlapping salaries.

Is there anything wrong in the code ? How to improve the results ?

Or whether clustering is not a right approach here ?
Then how can I cluster users only based on salary ?

```
 km.fit(data['salary'])
```

EDIT:

I figured out a way to solve my problem using [numpy.reshape](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)

```
km.fit(data['salary'].reshape(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

K-means is based on the assumption that the data is "translation invariant" (more precisely: variance does, and k-means is variance minimization).

In other words, it assumes that a difference of d=(x-y)^2 is of the *same* importance everywhere. Because of this, **k-means does not work on skewed data**. Furthermore, because of the square, it is **sensitive to outliers and other extreme values**.

For salaries and other monetary values, this usually does not hold. The difference between \$0 and \$1000 is massive, and not the same as a salary difference of \$100000 to \$101000. Salaries are usually rather skewed, and you often have some extreme values.

**Converting the "user" attribute to a numerical value is outright statistical nonsense**. What's variance worth in this attribute? **K-means is for continuous numerical data only**, and converting data does not chnage the *nature*, only the encoding - it's still inappropriate.

Comment: do you mind explaining what's "translation invariant"? Do you have proof or any reference in literature to claim that k-means does not work on skewed data?

Comment: yes I got your point, so this is not a typical clustering problem. right ? Then the best way is to sort salaries based on score and divide them to 'K'  categories right ?  Also is there a way to calculate the best number for 'K' ? suggestions please.

Comment: @TuN. I already gave an example... beware, there are two kinds of skewedness. Some are fine, e.g. if your data is 1000 objects from N(1, 1) and 100 from N(10,1) then this is will be considered a skewed variable, but probably fine for k-means because the clusters are well separated and not skewed themselves.

Comment: @Sreejithc321 I don't know if you have a "typical clusteeing problem" because you have not stated the problem. What are *valid* answers to your problem, and what makes one answer *better* than another. Until you specify this, random assignment is a valid solution to your problem.

Comment: For 1 dimensional and 2 dimensional data, I suggest you also visualize the data (and any result) and discuss what is interesting, bad, difficult, desired on the *plot*. Datascience is about telling a story, and images help a lot there.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I don't think your claim is correct. K-means can be seen as a EM algorithm on Gaussian Mixtures, so skewedness doesn't make K-means work better or worse. Skewedness of data is likely to skew up the initialization process of centroids, which make K-means trap in local optima. That's being said, even if you have balanced data, K-means might not work because of bad initialization.

Comment: No, k-means is not assuming Gaussian mixtures. GMM is the usual EM approach; and it is just as much affected by skewed distributions, because it assumes Gaussians which are non-skewed. Apply exp() to all values, and your clustering result will become substantially worse.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a 'clustering' problem as much at is it an 'interval' problem since you only have 1 dimension.

You can use an iterative process like [Jenk's natural break optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_natural_breaks_optimization) in order to figure out how large to make your intervals.

As other posters have said, do not user names as a clustering dimension unless you really think that variations in letters of a name are meaningful in some way (do you really think all the Dan's are paid similarly?).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is using the name as a dimension. You can, but you have to use a more robust distance metric between names (string). As far as I know, LabelEncoder just assign an int considering the element's order of ocurrence in a unique list. You could try a different hashing (string to int) or [Levenshtein_distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) as a distance metric

Comment: How can I fit only salary ? km.fit(data['salary']) ?

Comment: You don't have any other attribute? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40454/determine-different-clusters-of-1d-data-from-database

Comment: no other attribures

Comment: You should try another technique instead of clustering, read the link above